# Sorting waypoints into groups embedded within single GPX file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps

[image]

I am using QGIS 2.18. I transfer the GPS data from my Garmin GPSMAP64s in the form of GPX file format. After opening one GPX file I got many waypoints which I previously marked in the field. Now I want to symbolize these waypoints in three different groups. But after saving the GPX file in shapefile format I can't sort these waypoints in groups. I want to show these waypoints in three different coloured symbol.

Comment: Please post a screen shot of the shapefile table and how you would like to separate the points into 3 groups.

Comment: Please see the table. I want to group BBL, OSL and PFP by separate colours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rule-based renderer to achieve this. I have not used QGIS 2.18 for nearly 5 years and I would really recommend updating to a recent version, but this should still work fine in 2.18 (although the interface might be slightly different).

Select rule-based renderer in the Symbology tab of layer properties dialog (or in the layer styling dock). Then set up your rules by setting filters for each of the groups you want (click the green Plus sign to add additional rules) e.g.

```
"name" LIKE '%BBL'
"name" LIKE '%OSL'
"name" LIKE '%PFP'
```

You can then set the label and marker symbol for each rule category, changing color, shape, size etc. as you wish. You can either do this when you set up each rule or later by double clicking on each row in the rule table.

Maybe you will find this outdated [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification) for version 2.14 helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben. It works nicely.

Comment: @Supratim Mukherjee, great. Glad to hear it worked. In that case, would you mind marking the answer as accepted? https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers